# Passing array to external function in inline assembly

Tags: solidity, arrays, assembly

How can I pass a (nested) array to an external function if the call is made within an inline assembly block? I wrote the following little test contract and everything works just fine until I add the array parameter.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract AssemblyTest {

    function getFromMatrix(uint x, uint y, uint[][] memory matrix) external pure returns (uint) {
        // return x + y; // works fine without the matrix parameter
        return matrix[y][x]; // always 0
    }

    function test() external view returns (uint) {
        bytes4 selector = this.getFromMatrix.selector;
        uint[][] memory matrix = new uint[][](3);
        for (uint i; i < 3; i++) {
          matrix[i] = new uint[](3);
          for (uint j; j < 3; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = i * 3 + j;
          }
        }
        assembly {
            function allocate(size) -> ptr {
                ptr := mload(0x40)
                if iszero(ptr) { ptr := 0x60 }
                mstore(0x40, add(ptr, size))
            }
            let x := 1
            let y := 1
            let mem := allocate(0x64)
            mstore(mem, selector)
            mstore(add(mem, 0x04), x)
            mstore(add(mem, 0x24), y)
            mstore(add(mem, 0x44), matrix)
            let success := staticcall(gas(), address(), mem, 0x64, 0, 0x20)
            return (0, 0x20)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your data is not abi encoded for the staticcall, you can either fix it by encoding outside of assembly or write the proper assembly to generate the appropriate calldata, which one are you looking for ?

Comment: I would like to have as much as possible in assembly, just to get my head around all the low level things.

Comment: @Daniel For calls to an external function you have to encode using the [solidity abi](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html).